# Install certificate .cer and pfx on setup desktop program c#

Tags: c#, pfx, certificate-store, cer

how can i install two certificates (pfx with password) during my setup is installing on pc? I need Two certificates located on personal->certificates because desktop program is used for all users on this pc.

I'm using .net 3.5

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind defining "my setup" more closely? Do you already use a setup software of a specific vendor or are you in the planning phase of creating a setup project?

Answer (score 1):

This below will extract the Public & Private key from the `.PFX` file and parse it into an `X509Certificate2` object (`X509Certificate` type does not support Private keys and is unable understand V2 & V3 properties). You then pass `X509Certificate2` object to the local certificate repository which is currently set to `LocalMachine` as I'm guessing that's where you want it according to the image you attached.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\key.pfx", "test1234", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet); //Saves in the local machine store - accessible for all users

  using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
  {
     store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite); //Set to Write - You need Admin Permissions
     store.Add(cert); //Add Private Cert to Store
  }
```

I recommend that you read this [post](http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2) by Paul Stovell before diving head first as permissions could be nightmare especially within a domain environment (Active Directory).